# xcode 9 irrlicht engine build error: unknown type name 'u32'

Tags: c++, xcode, irrlicht

I use irrlicht engine for my ios game, everything works fine before xcode 9. But after I update my xcode to 9th version, when I compile my engine, xcode shows many buildtime errors, mainly are the **unknown type name 'u32' error** and which typedef in 'types.h' of the engine. 
Here is some of the source code in the types.h:

```
    namespace irrlicht
    {

     /** These are typedef for basic types, it ensures portability of the engine. */

    typedef unsigned char   u8;         //! 8 bit unsigned variable.
    typedef signed char     s8;         //! 8 bit signed variable.
    typedef char            c8;         //! 8 bit character variable.

    typedef unsigned short  u16;        //! 16 bit unsigned variable.
    typedef signed short    s16;        //! 16 bit signed variable.

    typedef unsigned int  u32;//! 32 bit unsigned variable.

    typedef signed int      s32;        //! 32 bit signed variable.
    typedef float           f32;        //! 32 bit floating point variable.
    ...
```

anyone knows how to fix this? Many thanks!